# Tree not updating nodes position when adding a new sibling

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code which draws a very simple tree. On clicking any node I'm calling the update function with new data to add a new child at the bottom of the tree.

The new node is added but the sibling node does not update it's position.

If I log out nodes:

```
var nodes = root.descendants();
console.log(nodes);
```

I can see that the position x,y has been correctly updated but I get an overlapping effect where the previous node has not moved position.

What Am I doing wrong here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<style>
    .node {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ddd;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>

<body>
  <svg width="1500" height="920">
      <g transform="translate(550, 100)">
          <g class="links"></g>
          <g class="nodes"></g>
      </g>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var treeData = {
          "name": "root",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "ORIG"
            }
         ]
      }

      var treeLayout = d3.tree()
        .size([900, 200])
        .nodeSize([210, 40])

function update(data) {

    var root = d3.hierarchy(data);

    treeLayout(root);

    var nodes = root.descendants();
    var links = root.links();

    var nodeWidth = 190;
    var nodeHeight = 90;

    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 170;
    });

    // Nodes
    const nodesEnter = d3.select('.nodes')
      .selectAll('.node')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .classed('node', true)
      .attr("width", 190)
      .attr("height", 90)
      .attr('x', function(d) {return d.x;})
      .attr('y', function(d) {return d.y;})
      .on("click", click);

    // Links
    d3.select('.links')
      .selectAll('.link')
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .classed('link', true)
      .attr('x1', function(d, i) {return d.source.x + (nodeWidth / 2);})
      .attr('y1', function(d) {return d.source.y + (nodeHeight);})
      .attr('x2', function(d) {return d.target.x + (nodeWidth / 2);})
      .attr('y2', function(d) {return d.target.y + 0;});

      function click(d) {

          update({
              "name": "root",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "ORIG"
              },
              {
                "name": "NEW"
              }
             ]
          });
      }
}

update(treeData);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to use the join pattern correctly, there are many questions on SO regarding this

Comment: I thought I was joining the data by doing  `.selectAll('.node'); .data(nodes)`?

Comment: read the data join in the d3 docs (d3-selection)

Comment: Yeah read this: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ and the docs. Not sure why what I'm doing doesn't constitute a join, hence posting here.

Comment: From here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218: `
// DATA JOIN
  // Join new data with old elements, if any.
  var text = g.selectAll("text")
    .data(data);
`

Comment: make a close inspection of both source codes (yours and mikes) and you will see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a D3 data binding (`d3.select(s).data(d)`), we should be prepared to do 3 things:

- `enter`, which adds a geom for each element in our data that's not yet in the selected DOM,
- `transition`, which changes each selected element in the DOM using the new data, and
- `exit`, which removes elements from the DOM if we have less data than elements in the selected DOM.

In your case, you just need to update your `update()` function to perform each of these three actions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head></head>
<style>
    .node {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ddd;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>

<body>
  <svg width="1500" height="920">
      <g transform="translate(550, 100)">
          <g class="links"></g>
          <g class="nodes"></g>
      </g>
  </svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var treeData = {
          "name": "root",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "ORIG"
            }
         ]
      }

      var treeLayout = d3.tree()
        .size([900, 200])
        .nodeSize([210, 40])

function update(data) {

    var root = treeLayout(d3.hierarchy(data)),
        nodes = root.descendants(),
        links = root.links(),
        nodeWidth = 190,
        nodeHeight = 90;

    nodes.forEach(d => d.y = d.depth * 170)

    // Nodes
    const node = d3.select('.nodes').selectAll('.node').data(nodes)

    node.enter()
      .append('rect')
      .classed('node', true)
      .attr("width", 190)
      .attr("height", 90)
      .attr('x', d => d.x)
      .attr('y', d => d.y)
      .on("click", click)

    node.transition()
      .attr('x', d => d.x)
      .attr('y', d => d.y)

    node.exit()
      .remove()

    // Links
    const link = d3.select('.links').selectAll('.link').data(links)

    link.enter()
        .append('line')
        .classed('link', true)
        .attr('x1', d => d.source.x + (nodeWidth / 2))
        .attr('y1', d => d.source.y + (nodeHeight))
        .attr('x2', d => d.target.x + (nodeWidth / 2))
        .attr('y2', d => d.target.y)

    link.transition()
        .attr('x1', d => d.source.x + (nodeWidth / 2))
        .attr('y1', d => d.source.y + (nodeHeight))
        .attr('x2', d => d.target.x + (nodeWidth / 2))
        .attr('y2', d => d.target.y)

    link.exit()
        .remove()

      function click(d) {
          update({
              "name": "root",
              "children": [
                {
                    "name": "ORIG"
                },
                {
                  "name": "NEW"
                }
             ]
          });
      }
}

update(treeData);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to review data bindings more, I put together a little [tutorial on data binding in D3](https://github.com/YaleDHLab/lab-workshops/tree/master/intro-to-d3#create-edit-and-delete-content-with-data-bindings) here that may help.

Comment: Hi Duhaime, thanks for your answer. I'd just realised where I was going wrong but hadn't got the transition sorted yet. Tutorial looks great - I'm going to go through it now.

Comment: nice all that unnecessary code duplication. look at the examples from Mike

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks. The .merge() pattern is nicer, but for pedagogical reasons it makes sense to start with unfactored code. Once the OP figures out the general update pattern they can factor. Before V4 all D3 code was duplicative as above

Comment: we are not using d3v3 any more, and code duplication should be eliminated at all times (maintenance), even with d3v3 it can be done without code duplication

Comment: @rioV8 are you kidding me? OP is struggling with the basics, why would you pressure them to write or learn beautiful factored code? If you want to write a factored answer, I won't stop you. Good day

Comment: because the only good code is **beautiful factored code**, why should I repeat what has already been answered in dozens of SO questions and what has been written in good D3 articles on the web.