# Unable to update SVG element using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to `d3` and am trying to learn the basics, I have drawn a circle and want to update it using function calls.

This code works as expected and draws a circle:

```
const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.append('g').selectAll('circle')
  .data([50])
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cy', 60)
  .attr('cx', 100)
  .attr('r', function(d) { return d; });
```

Now I create a function which takes an array to update the `data` property and change the radius of my circle:

```
function update(data) {
  const circle = svg.select('g').select('circle').data(data);
  circle.enter().append('circle').attr('r', function(d) { return d; });
}

update([100])
```

If I call `console.log(circle.data())` the value is set correctly but the circle is sadly still on 50px in radius on the screen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53130898/9938317 within 1 hour 2 people with the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a D3 data binding (`d3.select(s).data(d)`), we should be prepared to do 3 things:

- `enter`, which adds a geom for each element in our data that's not yet in the selected DOM,
- `transition`, which changes each selected element in the DOM using the new data, and
- `exit`, which removes elements from the DOM if we have less data than elements in the selected DOM.

In your case, you just need to update your `update()` function to perform each of these three actions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head></head>
<body>
  <svg width="1500" height="920"></svg>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  const svg = d3.select('svg');
  svg.append('g').selectAll('circle')
    .data([50])
    .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cy', 600)
      .attr('cx', 700)
      .attr('r', function(d) { return d; })
      .attr('fill', 'red');

  function update(data) {
    const circle = svg.select('g').select('circle').data(data);
    circle.enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', function(d) { return d; });

    circle.transition()
      .attr('r', function(d) { return d; });

    circle.exit()
      .remove()
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    update([100])
  }, 500)

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The trouble with your approach is you weren't calling `transition` in your update function. We need to use transition to modify elements that match the selection.

If you want to review data bindings more, I put together a little [tutorial on data binding in D3](https://github.com/YaleDHLab/lab-workshops/tree/master/intro-to-d3#create-edit-and-delete-content-with-data-bindings) here that may help.

Comment: Thank you! This does work, however - is this is the only way to modify the UI after the data element is updated? EDIT: ok this is more clear now with your edit!

Comment: @ydennis no of course not, there are lots of ways to modify the dom after you call the enter block. Try running in the console `document.querySelector('circle').setAttribute('r', 5)`. Maybe I'm not understanding you

Comment: what I meant was that `transition` felt more of a styling element, but when I just want to `update` I expected a different approach? I do not want to directly manipulate the DOM would rather learn the d3 way.

Comment: good, it's best to only mutate D3 elements with D3 methods, else the data can become unbound from the UI. Yes, transition should be used to change any properties of rendered elements, whether those properties are aesthetic or not. You could also check out the `merge` method, which is new in D3 v4, and which combines the `.enter` and `.transition` methods to make selections on elements in both of those groups -- it's pretty neat!